# Do bug bounties ensure that software is secure?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, software

I've been looking into third-party encryption tools and noticed that this [particular provider](https://nordlocker.com/locker-bounty/) has a bounty going on. Does this mean that they take security more seriously than other providers? How long can bounties like this last? I'd like to see some examples if there are any similar going on right now or have been in the past.

Answer (score 4):

> Do bug bounties ensure that software is secure?

No, they don't **ensure** that software is secure. But they might lead to **more secure** software if the bounty means that the vendor is actually committed to better security.

> Does this mean that they take security more seriously than other providers?

Usually vendors who have bug bounty **programs** invest more resources into keeping the software secure. With single target bug bounties this can (but don't need to) be different. Such cracking contests might be more a marketing thing so that the software can be marketed as "unbreakable even by experts". In these case the bug bounty often does not cover typical real world attacks. See also [The Fallacy of Cracking Contests](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1215.html#contests)
.

> How long can bounties like this last?

This is fully up to the vendor.

> I'd like to see some examples if there are any similar going on right now or have been in the past.

A search for [bug bounty unbreakable cryptography](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Zb-hXrLAINKhkwWviqrIBw&q=%22bug+bounty%22+%22unbreakable%22+%22cryptography%22) gives you other such programs.

Comment: I'd like to add that _nothing_ ensures that software is secure because you cannot prove that any non-trivial software is devoid of errors or misconceptions. However, the fact that a vendor has a bug bounty program at least shows that this vendor has recognized that the security of their software is an important aspect, and that it is helpful rather than harmful to discover any problems, so they can be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

No, a bug bounty program in no way grants assurance of secure software. Software will always have bugs. There is no "silver bullet" tool or process that will eliminate 100% of security vulnerabilities. A good security team will look to implement bug prevention measures at every stage of the SDLC that they can, an approach commonly referred to as "defense in depth". Bug bounties can be implemented in several ways (privately, publicly, time bound, indefinitely, etc.) to cover different parts of the SDLC and thus provide another layer of depth to a company's security strategy.

A great example of defense in depth using bounties is Facebook, which runs their own public bug bounty program. As you can see from the graphic below, Facebook utilizes their bounty program as a last line of defense against bugs. It allows anyone to help the Facebook security team identify security vulnerabilities that are already live on production Facebook assets:

[image: Defense in Depth at Facebook]

Image credit and more information on Facebook's bounty program: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/facebook-details-the-defense-in-depth-approach-used-to-secure-its-platform

Report a security vulnerability to Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/whitehat